# Permissions broken after upgrade from 2016 to 2019

Tags: permissions, upgrade

Trying to upgrade my SharePoint from 2016 to 2019.
I have completed all the steps in the upgrade. Once this has been completed no account has access to any Sharepoint site even the farm admin account.

If I run `Convert-SPWebapplication` to convert to Claims(which was done when we moved to 2016) it will give the account I'm running command with access to the whole site. Once I can do that I can go into Sharepoint and see that all the permissions are there as they should be but take no effect.
I can go to a permissions page look for a user or group in the list and go to check permissions and check that group that is listed on that page and it will come up with 'none' for permissions
If I then add that same user or group to that page it will add that user in again and it will appear in the list a 2nd time and its permissions will work.
If I query the permissions through PowerShell I can see the permissions listed but the one i have added in manually will have its ID and not its name in the name column.

if I try and add or remove permissions through PowerShell I get the initial problem of the permissions will show on the permissions page but not have any effect.
I have tried copying the UPS database from the 2016 server as well and still have the same problem.